# Copy value out of users input to another channel

Tags: javascript, chatbot, slack, slack-api

I am working on a chatbot for school that solves problems in my school. So basically I'm stuck on this part because I have no idea how to do this...

- I want to check if a certain value in a sentence is equal to a value in my array.
- If it is equal to a value in my array, then I want my chatbot to write a message to another channel containing that variable

So lets say I have the sentence:

> Hi, I have a problem in classroom 108

The value "classroom 108" is equal to the value "classroom 108" in my array.

```
   var classroom= [
    {
        L108: ["classroom 108","L108"]
    },{
        L208: ["classroom 208","L208"]
    }
];
```

So now I want to write a message to another channel containing the variable "L108".

```
function handleMessage(message) {
     classroom.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (message.includes(classroom)) {
            classroom();
            console.log(message);
        };
    })
};
function classroom(message) {
    const params = {
        icon_emoji: ':smiley:'
    }
    textchannel = probleemoplosser + ", een docent heeft een probleem met het " + probleem + " in ",classroom, params;
    reactie =  "Top, ik heb het doorgegeven aan " + naam;
    bot.postMessageToChannel( otherchannel,textchannel,params);
    bot.postMessageToChannel('general',reactie, params);
};
```

I don't have much experience with JavaScript so any help is welcome...thanks in advance!<3

Comment: Hey, is this the updated version of your former question? If so please delete the old version. thanks (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084029/how-to-copy-a-certain-value-in-users-input-to-another-channel)

Comment: What are the specific issues you have with your code? What is not working? Are you getting error messages?

Comment: The problem is that I don’t know how to copy a single value out of the users input to another channel. If that is possible ofcourse

Comment: So there is a main channel where the user says his problem. What I want is a certain value out of that message and message it to another channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of your code. I took the liberty to restructure and rename functions and variables to improve readability.

The main thing missing in your original code was an inner loop that goes through all terms and compares them.

```
var classrooms = {
  L108: ["classroom 108","L108"],    
  L208: ["classroom 208","L208"]
};

// returns classroom ID if classroom is mentioned in message string
// else returns false
function findClassroomMention(message) {
  var found = false
  for (var classroomId in classrooms) {    
    for (var term of classrooms[classroomId]) {
      if (message.includes(term)) {
        found = classroomId;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (found) break;
  }
  return found
};

// sends notification to problem solver channel about a classroom
function notifyProblemSolver(classroomId) {
  // TODO: dummy function to be replaced with bot code
  console.log('We need help with classroom ' + classroomId)    
};

// example message
var message = 'Hi, I have a problem in classroom 108'

var classroomId = findClassroomMention(message)
if (classroomId) {
  notifyProblemSolver(classroomId)
}
```

See [here](https://playcode.io/475037) for a live demo.

Comment: So what I don't get is the part: var found = false. Why is it false?

Comment: And also the //example message is not part of the actual code right?

Comment: correct. the example message is not part of the solution. it's just for showing that it works

Comment: the logic with found is: the function will return the value of found. found will be false, unless a term matches and found is set to a classroom ID. In other words. if the function does not find a match it will return false.

Comment: Hi got one more problem if you feel like answering. I am trying to link the function messageProblemSolver to the function findClassroomMention, but it isn't working.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Have you tried just using my example (last 4 lines)?

Comment: Basically I have written a function that messages the problem solver. But when I write:

Comment: if (message.includes(term) {                                                                                    found = classroomId;                                                                                                        messageProblemSolver()   }                                                                                                      {        if (found) messageProblemSolver(); break;             }

Comment: My example is designed so that you don't need to call your message function from within the for loop (because I think its not good design). the function `notifyProblemSolver()` is supposed to send the message.